# Why does my character stop moving after changig a 0 to 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm following a basic unity tutorial and this is the code for it but my character stops moving after I change the 0 here to a 1 and it is done in the tutorial. Can you help me?
I tried to look at the code of the video's creator but I could not find any differences. This is the video I was following https://youtu.be/pwZpJzpE2lQ

`if (Physics.OverlapSphere(groundCheckTransform.position, 0.1f).Length == 1)`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Transform groundCheckTransform = null;
private bool jumpKeyWasPressed;
private float horizontalInput;
private Rigidbody rigidbodyComponent;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rigidbodyComponent = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        jumpKeyWasPressed = true;
    }

    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

//Fixed update is called every physics update
private void FixedUpdate()
{   if (Physics.OverlapSphere(groundCheckTransform.position, 0.1f).Length == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
   

    if (jumpKeyWasPressed)
    {
        rigidbodyComponent.AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        jumpKeyWasPressed = false;
    }

    rigidbodyComponent.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 
rigidbodyComponent.velocity.y, 0);
}
```

Comment: The code makes no sense. There must be a copy-paste-issue. It is having the if block without an inner block and this if is outside any method block. Plz check your sample code.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt I think the very first line is supposed to show where they change the value. It is repeated in the FixedUpdate()

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the priority of writing the code, when your code reach the `return` keyword it will stop running the function. The resume of function codes do not work. Changing the code to the following will solve the problem.

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbodyComponent.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 
        rigidbodyComponent.velocity.y, 0);
    
    if (Physics.OverlapSphere(groundCheckTransform.position, 0.1f).Length == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (jumpKeyWasPressed)
    {
        rigidbodyComponent.AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        jumpKeyWasPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. So i changed my code to look like that but now my character moves only left and right. How can I get my character to jump now?

Comment: @PaavoIsberg change Length == 1 to 0 back again.

Comment: The point of changing the 0 to a 1 is to make the character not able not jump infinitely

Comment: @PaavoIsberg Unfortunately it has nothing to do! The condition you wrote is relevant to the ground detector, you must create a jump counting system to limit the jump.