# My character does not jump after doing as suggested in my previous question

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character doesn't jump after I tried a fix suggested to me in my previous question linked below. It only moves left and right and if i remove what i changed it doesn't move at all.
[Why does my character stop moving after changig a 0 to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474911/why-does-my-character-stop-moving-after-changig-a-0-to-1)

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheckTransform = null;
    private bool jumpKeyWasPressed;
    private float horizontalInput;
    private Rigidbody rigidbodyComponent;
   

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbodyComponent = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            jumpKeyWasPressed = true;
        }

        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }

    //Fixed update is called every physics update
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbodyComponent.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput,
            rigidbodyComponent.velocity.y, 0);
        if (Physics.OverlapSphere(groundCheckTransform.position, 0.1f).Length == 1)
        {
            return;
        }
       

        if (jumpKeyWasPressed)
        {

            rigidbodyComponent.AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            jumpKeyWasPressed = false;
        }

        rigidbodyComponent.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 
    rigidbodyComponent.velocity.y, 0);
    }

    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use same code twice in the beginning and the end of fixed update block. It might not be the problem but maybe your addForce is not working because you define new values for same variables in the same cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with the ground check if statement (`if (Physics.OverlapSphere`...)

I'm not really familiar with that use of Physics.OverlapSphere, and I don't know what the .Length is supposed to return, but I suspect the following:

Your ground check is testing to see if the character is on the ground, and then only running `return;` which then skips the rest of the code, thus never running the jump code if the player is on the ground? Maybe you need to put the jump code into the groundcheck if statement, like this:

```
if (Physics.OverlapSphere(groundCheckTransform.position, 0.1f).Length == 1)
    {
        if (jumpKeyWasPressed)
        {

            rigidbodyComponent.AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            jumpKeyWasPressed = false;
        }
    }
```

Remember `return;` immediately stops the function, and returns its value or no value. All the code after the `return;` will be skipped.

Maybe use Debug.Log() to send messages to console to debug this more. If you put one in the ground check if statement, you can see when it is succeeding and when it is failing (if it fails then the jump if statement will run, so if it always succeeds then the jump statement will always be skipped.)

Feel free to ask me to clarify if that was confusing.